# Unble to use the working Django modles for index.html page ( Modles data entried in admin page but not visible in index.html page)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created modles in modles.py as below:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

, migrate successfully, later on, registered the moodle in admin.py as

```
admin.site.register(Title),
```

But the issue is I can see in admin pannel that modles created and upadted the data but in index.html page, I used as {{Title.title}} which seems not working. Need help ????? Do i need to create views and what I should types in views.py

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten my answer as I have to use for loop in order to work my models.